# Почему в глобальные переменных могут попадать разные значения?

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, почему в GET может сохраняться неверное значение? POST и COOKIE таких ключей не имеют. Слово "index" присутствует в url. Куда копать?

Строка запроса: https://domain.loc/api/elements/index/list?hash=35de7b7068&asdf=sadfsadfasdf

Сервер - nginx + php-fpm

Comment: Строку запроса с параметрами добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Судя по запросу, где-то в nginx происходит rewrite. Нужен конфиг nginx

Answer (score 0):

Дело может быть в настройке заполнение глобальных массивов http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order, если порядок заполнение установлен как **EGPCS** то при передаче $_GET['hash'] и $_POST['hash'], в $_REQUEST['hash'] попадает именно $_POST['hash'], потому что P идет после G